# Problem understanding sign of volume integral in Minkowski space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, wick-rotation

My professor told me that a 4-dimensional Minkowski - Space Integral I was working on can be written as the product of a metric tensor and a scalar:

$\int d^4 k  \frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{(k^2-m_1^2)(k^2-m_2^2)} = g^{\mu \nu} B_2$

where $B_2$ is a scalar.

I am surprised that apparently for $\mu = \nu = 0$ , the sign of the integral is opposite to the sign for, say, $\mu = \nu = 1$. This seems wrong to me, and in an Eucledian Space it certainly would be. If I had been asked to guess, I would have written the above equation with $ g^\mu_\nu B_2$ on the right hand side instead..

Can someone bring clarity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key insight is that the integral you wrote down is a Lorentz-invariant tensor, so whatever it evaluates to must also be Lorentz-invariant.

To illustrate this, let's be a bit more general and consider any integral of the form
\begin{align}
  I^{\mu\nu}[f] = \int d^4k\, f(k^2)k^\mu k^\nu
\end{align}
for any admissible function $f$.  Then notice that for any Lorentz transformation $\Lambda = (\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\nu})$ we have
\begin{align}
  \Lambda^\alpha_{\phantom\alpha\mu}\Lambda^\beta_{\phantom\beta\nu}\,I^{\mu\nu}[f] 
&= \int d^4k\, f(k^2)(\Lambda^\alpha_{\phantom\alpha\mu}k^\mu)( \Lambda^\beta_{\phantom\beta\nu}k^\nu)\\
&= \int d^4 u f(u^2) u^\alpha u^\beta \\
&= I^{\alpha\beta}[f]
\end{align}
where in the second equality we made the change of variables $u^\alpha = \Lambda^\alpha_{\phantom\alpha\mu}k^\mu$, and we noted that the term $f(k^2)$ becomes $f(u^2)$ because $k^2$ is Lorentz-invariant, and the measure $d^4 k$ is Lorentz-invariant.

**Addendum.** (Following comments on answer v1)

The above argument demonstrates that provided $f$ is such that $I^{\mu\nu}[f]$ is well-defined, the integral is a Lorentz-invariant two-tensor and therefore is of the form $g^{\mu\nu}B[f]$ for some scalar functional $B$ as you wrote.

However, as is it is written, the integral you wrote down is divergent both because the integrand is singular (it has poles at $k^2 = m_1^2$ and $k^2 = m_2^2$), and by power counting which shows that the integrand scales linearly with $k$ for large $k$ so it is UV divergent.   This ill-definedness leads to all sorts of apparent "paradoxes."  For example, as pointed out by user10001, if we were to set $m_1 = m_2$, then the integrand is manifestly positive unless $k^\mu = 0$, so how could $I^{00}$ and $I^{ii}$ have different signs?

The resolution is to note that this integral comes from QFT where one uses the so-called $i\epsilon$ prescription (for good physics reasons) which removes the poles from the integrand by shifting them away from the real axis.  Moreover, one fixes the UV divergence by regularizing the integral (using e.g. dimensional regularization).  The object one then needs to compute is
\begin{align}
  I^{\mu\nu}(d) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R^4} d^dk \frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{(k^2 - m_1^2 + i\epsilon)(k^2-m_2^2+i\epsilon)}, \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}
for $d\neq 4$ and then analytically continue this to a function $I^{\mu\nu}(z)$ on the complex plain (minus some isolated singular points) which allows one to parametrize the divergence near $d=4$ by plugging in $z = 4-\epsilon$.

Note that $(\star)$ is not plagued by any of the apparent paradoxes that concerned us in the comments.

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly fine but there is still a paradox here that I am not able to understand. From the OP's integral we can see that for $m_1=m_2$ the integral is positive for all $\mu=\nu$, simply because the integrand is positive and also the measure $d^4 k =dk^0 dk^1 dk^2 dk^3$ is positive; whereas if the value of integral were equal to $g^{\mu\nu} B_2$ then the sign of integral for $\mu=\nu=0$ will be opposite to that for $\mu=\nu=i,\: i=1,2,3$!

Comment: I am right there with user10001. Your argument is very nicely elaborated and tells us what has to be the result by means of an "outer"  argument. But how do we resolve what is seemingly a paradox, the fact that all integrals, calculated explicitly, seem to be positive?

Comment: @user10001 Yes, that's a great observation, but I think we have to be very careful here for the following reason.  Notice that the integrand in the question has two poles at $k^2 = m_1^2$ and $k^2 = m_2^2$, so I'm guessing this is a loop integral in QFT in which case you're missing $i\epsilon$'s, otherwise the integral is ill-defined (divergent). Once one does this, the integrand is no longer manifestly non-negative, and the objection goes away.  Moreover, even after you do this, I think you need to regularize the integral since the integrand scales like $k$ for $k$ large.

Comment: @Konstantin In any event, I'll try to incorporate my comments above addressed to user10001 into an addendum to the answer that more explicitly addresses these issues (particularly inclusion of the $i\epsilon$ prescription) as soon as I can.

Comment: @Josh Yeah that seems to resolve this paradox. More generally, it appears that the integrals of Lorentz covariant real integrands can never be finite on Minkowski space {in particular, integrals of the form $\int d^4 p f(p^2)^2 p^\mu p^\nu$ can not be finite}, and we necessarily have to go to Euclidean space to make sense of these integrals by assuming p0 to be a complex variable and making use of Wick rotation. The reason that they are not finite is  may be because any function of the form f(p^2) doesn't go to zero at infinty on Minkowski space.

Comment: @user10001 Yeah I think I agree with your last comment.    I had the same thought about general behavior of functions $f(p^2)$ where $p^2$ is the Minkowski square, but I'm not prepared to make any definitive claims as I'm pretty rusty on this stuff.  I should add though that I don't think this is so much an issue of Wick rotation, which is just a tricky way of computing an already well-defined expression by deforming a contour.  I think the $i\epsilon$ is really the key, because it moves the poles off-axis.

Comment: @Josh I am not sure but I think the $i\epsilon$ contour can always be rotated to y-axis contour i.e. to Euclidean space. Anyway, all I was saying is that the integrals on Minkowski space itself are ill defined, and in order to make sense of them one needs to choose a different p0 contour in complex p0 plane other than the real axis.

Comment: @user10001 Yeah you're right; my last comment was misleading and borderline wrong since, as you point out, going to Euclidean space chooses the right contour.  Thanks for all the great observations by the way; I had forgotten about these subtleties.

Comment: @Josh Thanks to you too; I never cared much about $i\epsilon$ Now I understand that its not just important but really necessary:)

Comment: @joshphysics Thank you for all the explainations. I will accept the answer after you incorporate the essence of your very useful comments into it.

Comment: @Konstantin I added an addendum; let me know if you find any errors.

Comment: @joshphysics: Hi Josh. Do you happen to know any reference containing a rigorous mathematical proof that $ {I^{\mu \nu}}(d) $ can be analytically continued to a meromorphic function on $ \mathbb{C} $? I have seen a proof for Feynman integrals in Euclidean space (using some result of Joseph Bernstein), but I have yet to see one for Feynman integrals in Minkowski space. Of course, one can say, “Just perform a Wick rotation.” However, I think some justification is needed.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore Not off the top of my head, but I'll let you know if I dig anything up.

Comment: Hello Josh, Maybe some stupid question, but I'm not quite sure about it... When you write $\int_{\mathbb{M}} d^4k$ is the time component equally treated as the space components, so essentially an integral over $\mathbb{R}^4$? Does $d^4k$ mean $dk^0 \,  dk^1 \, dk^2 \,  dk^3$ or $dk_0 \, dk_1 \, dk_2 \, dk_3$? Eventually these only differ by a sign, but I always mix that up.