# Rotational symmetry in integration

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, integration

Can someone please tell me why
$$4\int d^4x \, x^\mu x^\nu  ~=~\int d^4x \, g^{\mu\nu}x^2 $$
by some rotational symmetry argument?

Comment: What are your thoughts on it so far? It will help us answer if we know enough not to repeat your own progress.

Comment: Well, I know that $\int d^4x\,x^\mu=0.$ I feel that there really isn't much to say. Any hint might help me greatly...

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Integrands on both sides are not integrable functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you should check out this problem for some useful commentary.

[Problem understanding sign of volume integral in Minkowski space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114935/problem-understanding-sign-of-volume-integral-in-minkowski-space)

Essentially if you look at the integral on the LHS we see it takes the form explained in the problem above
$$
I^{\mu\nu}[f] = \int d^4k\, f(k^2)k^\mu k^\nu
$$
Where f is just 1

The integral is clearly Lorentz invariant (as shown in the question above). Our answer therefore must be the metric tensor (which is a rank 2 lorentz invariant tensor) times a scalar. By contracting each side with $$ g_{\mu\nu} $$

We find that scalar has to be equal to 
$$
\frac{1}{4} \int d^4x x^2
$$